# What's the maximum height of the cone with 33 degrees inside a regular tetrahedron?

Tags: geometry

The image of the problem: 
[image]

- The regular tetrahedron is 36 inches or 3 feet high.
- The cone is 33 degrees at the tip.
- The cone's tip has to be at the base when inside the regular tetrahedron.

What's the maximum height can the cone be inside the regular tetrahedron?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The answer I got is 19.56 inches based on this: http://i.imgur.com/3o7fNYF.png.

Comment: How did you get that number? My result is slightly different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By drawing the top and the side view of the tetrahedron we can calculate the maximum height of the cone.
[image]